# Laptop produces rhythmic sounds

Tags: macos, macbook

My Macbook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) started producing weird rhythmic sounds. It starts making the sound right from the boot up, and repeats every ~5 seconds. Here's a sample: https://yadi.sk/d/T1mfJAqlBVRmZA (ogg sound file)

What could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Kudos for providing a sound sample, but it's quite short and any rhythm is not terribly discernible. As it stands this is pretty broad. Can you [edit] your question to give more details- when does it do this, is it associated with it, has anything changed recently, etc. Cheers!

Comment: Based on the age of the machine and your description of the sound it’s a bad fan.

Comment: @appleoddity - well called. From the audio I'd gave postulated - incorrectly - a hard disk head crash.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you're trying to use the computer while diving under water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was the fan.

First thing I noticed was that my fan was dead silent, and it didn't respond when I tried to change it's speed. After I've opened up the laptop and unscrewed the fan I've found a little bit of stray plastic lying right beneath of it. Right after I removed the plastic, the fan started working properly again.